# convert python xgboost dMatrix to numpy ndarray or pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, xgboost

I'm following a xgboost example on their main git at -
https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/demo/guide-python/basic_walkthrough.py#L64

in this example they are reading files directly put into `dMatrix` -

```
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix('../data/agaricus.txt.train')
dtest = xgb.DMatrix('../data/agaricus.txt.test')
```

I looked at `dMatrix` code, seems there is no way to briefly look at how the data is structured - as we normally do in pandas with `pandas.DataFrame.head()`

in xgboost documentation it mentions that we can convert `numpy.ndarray` to `xgboost.dMatrix` - can we somehow convert it back - from `xgboost.dMatrix` to `numpy.ndarray`, or perhaps pandas dataFrame? I don't see possible way from their code - but perhaps someone knows a way?

Or is there a way to briefly look at how data is like in `xgboost.dMatrix`?

Thanks in advance,
Howard

Comment: It is possible by dmatrix2np package, you can see the code here: github.com/aporia-ai/dmatrix2np

Answer (score 6):

To elaborate on @jcaine's answer, you can use sklearn to load the files, then convert them to ordinary numpy arrays:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_svmlight_file
train_data = load_svmlight_file('demo/data/agaricus.txt.train')
X = train_data[0].toarray()
y = train_data[1]
```

I haven't found a way to directly convert from dMatrix to numpy arrays yet.

Answer (score 2):

Howard,

I believe that the xgb.DMatrix assumes the libsvm data format.  You can get this data into a sparse CSR matrix using scikit's load_svmlight_file: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_svmlight_file.html.

You can then partition the response variable and the features using the example at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1):

The package [dmatrix2np](https://github.com/aporia-ai/dmatrix2np) should do exactly that. From their docs:

```py
from dmatrix2np import dmatrix_to_numpy

converted_np_array = dmatrix_to_numpy(dmatrix)
```

If you don't have missing values then I think that the following should also work

```py
dmatrix.get_data().toarray()
```

the issue with missing values is that they will be treated as zeros instead of missing when you do that.